# Mistake correction in representing

Tags: professionalism

I have mistakenly said *"Dear Sir"* to a senior HR member, who is female, on LinkedIn. How should I professionally correct myself?

Comment: You had their name but still used Dear Sir/Madam? You do realise that if you have the name you should at least use Dear Mr/Mrs/Ms. *lastname*?

Comment: Draken, we don't know all the details. The addressee may not have had a picture on LinkedIn, and might have had a name that could go either way (Chris, Renee, Sam...memories of goofy SNL skits coming to mind). And frankly, these days, sometimes I look at a picture of someone and it isn't always obvious even then what the gender is.

Answer (score 14):

The best thing to do is nothing.

Faux Pas are common in the business world, and the proper thing to do in most cases is to ignore them.  I have a German last name and it is almost always mispronounced by Americans.  I ignore it, as should the person you addressed.

If no malice was intended, move on.  Literally any other course of action will only compound the problem.  It's a minor oversight and will likely be treated with amusement.

Answer (score 6):

If she is senior, and, being in HR receives a lot of messages, I am sure it has happened before, and she will cope without letting it affect how she handles the rest of your message.

The whole formal salutation business is a mess, and best just omitted.

Comment: How is it a mess? I would consider it rude if not included, in a message, from a strange

Comment: It is a mess because it requires a stranger to make guesses and assumption about the person addressed that are completely irrelevant to the actual communication. How would you address me?

Comment: Since I know your last name, Dear Ms. Shanahan

Comment: @Draken Wrong. I have a Phd in computer science, so in a professional or academic context its "Dear Dr. Shanahan". You just insulted me by reducing my academic status. :-) In reality, unless you did far more research than the issue is worth, you would have no way of knowing my correct title, which is exactly my point.

Comment: +1 Almost certainly, trying to correct yourself will come across far more awkwardly than the original faux pas.

Comment: Since I have no knowledge of your education and am unable to determine such a thing, until I know otherwise, Ms. is generally accepted. I would expect the same for people addressing me, if they don't know nor are not sure, use Mr. Expecting people to guess is all rather daft and assuming and if you feel insulted by it, that's a bit pretentious.

Comment: @Draken I strongly agree that "Expecting people to guess is all rather daft". That is why formal salutations are a mess - to get them right, you need to know quite a bit about the person addressed. Even gender is tricky - some given names can be male or female, and in any case the name to gender mapping depends on culture. Formal salutations are an outdated carry-over from face-to-face cultures in which you would rarely write a letter to someone you had never met and did not know much about.

Comment: In emails, salutations are NEVER needed.

Comment: @Draken And how would you address someone named Pat Shanahan?

Comment: @DavidK Dear M. Shanahan, if I'm not sure of the sex, I don't assume. All Mr, Ms can be shortened further to M.

Comment: @DavidK Good example. I switched from "Pat" to "Patricia" for work purposes due to a "Patrick Shanahan" who had been using "Pat Shanahan" for many years in the company I had just joined.

Comment: @Draken I have never once seen "M." used in a professional context. I would assume you got my initials wrong.

Comment: @Draken I find it very odd that you expect people to tolerate being addressed by completely incorrect titles, but consider simply skipping the salutation "rude".

Comment: It's the same as walking into a conversation without saying Hello, unless I know the people, I won't do it

Comment: @DavidK http://nonbinary.org/wiki/Gender_neutral_titles#M

Comment: @Draken You do realise you're quoting some random wiki? That list also includes Mx, Pr and sci-fi titles like Pr or Myr. I'm sure "M." will be used in certain circles but it's unheard of in the real world.

Comment: @Draken, as the linked article suggests, "M." is appropriate as a gender neutral title for someone who does not identify as strictly male or female. It is a *chosen* title for use when *you know the person prefers that title*. It is not appropriate for use when you simply don't know their gender. If you don't know which title to use, **leave it off**.

Comment: @HLGEM I strongly disagree with that claim, *especially* in this scenario. An email is a letter and a letter requires a salutation. If I get an email from a candidate I don't want the fact that he couldn't be bother to type "Dear [whatever]" to be the first thing I notice. (Edit: or are you referring to titles rather than salutations?)

Comment: Perhaps it is cultural but emails are not letters and when I was an editor (the job I had when emails came into being), we were taught that they should never have a salutation because the purpose of the salutation is accomplished in the to address. I don;t see emails in a professional context with formal salutations. The only time I ever see it start with some names is when the email is going to a whole laundry list of people but you only want one or two to take specific actions. Even then it would not start with "Dear..."  just " Dan, please provide...."

Comment: A simple, "Hello Pat," might work.  It is not as formal as "Dr. Mr. or Ms or Mrs." but it will often work.  In the real world, people generally don't care about a person's work title or credentials.  I'd never ask anyone to call me Dr. outside of that business relationship, and even then it is overly formal.

Comment: @MikeP "Hello Patricia" would be fine. Using an arbitrary contraction of someone's given name rather than the form they choose to use is not appropriate, although a lot of people do it.

Comment: While I *personally* agree with "The whole formal salutation business is a mess, and best just omitted", many people sadly expect them, and may interpret an email that lacks any salutation as being blunt, rude or presumptive (especially one that begins a conversation). It'd be great if that wasn't true, but sadly they're not going to disappear overnight. Something generic like "Greetings," "Good afternoon" or even just "Hello" can be a good fallback. It looks slightly unconventional, but only someone completely insufferable would think it rude, blunt or presumptive.